# Android download file name not corresponding to header

Tags: php, android, google-chrome, http-headers, content-disposition

I am using Nexus 7 to test, any other platforms don't have same situation as far I can test on. I use handle.php to handle the download, before `echo` the file content, I used:

```
header('Content-length:' . $row['size']);
header('Content-type:' . $row['mime']);
```

and

```
header('Content-Disposition:inline; filename="' . $row["file_name"] . '"');
```

then I use android to download the file, the file name is however `handle.pdf`, if I change the last row of my code into

```
header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="' . $row["file_name"] . '"');
```

and interesting, the file name became what I want. 
Does Android fail to get file name if the `Content-Disposition` is `inline` and only accept the file name with `attachment`?
By the way, I used the Native Chrome Browser (32.0) and in Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Per [RFC 2616, Sec 19](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html),

> The Content-Disposition response-header field has been proposed as a means for the origin server to suggest a default filename if the user requests that the content is saved to a file. This usage is derived from the definition of Content-Disposition in RFC 1806 [35].

Note that `filename-parm` is only specified for attachments, not for inline-content. While, in fact, most browsers parse the parameter and honor it, the standard doesn't call for that behavior. If you intent to deliver a file for download, you *should* set the content-disposition as `attachment`.

Comment: Thank you, and Is there any way I want desktop to open in browser and mobile device to download while the file name is kept as I want?

Comment: You will have to send different headers based on the UA. Send attachment with filename for mobile browsers and inline (with optional filename) for desktop browsers. Note that many sites, for example gmail, will have a View and a Download link which does exactly that.